# View not refreshing even after clearing cache laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, caching, view

I have written code in laravel and have managed it with GIT. 
Now I made some changes in the homepage which is not reflecting on the server but working well on the local system.

Things I tried to fix the issue

1. Cleared the cache, views also manually deleted from the framework folder in storage
2. Changed the cache method from file to array
3. Created a new server and deployed the code from git but got the same issue. (Yes the code in html file has the updated code and i can see it using vi and cat).
4. More importantly i can change the files in other html files in admin folder and it works fine and update is reflected in the browser.
5. i also tried deleting the view file but it does not work also tried copying the file with new name and using the view but no change in the result.

Please provide me with solution if anyone has ever faced it.

Comment: I faced same issue earlier too and at that time the config was angular + laravel. Did not got a fix but when i copied the content to new view file and pointed to it. It worked. Same system is working when i change anything on other page in admin panel but not on the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a index.html file in the public folder. Which was being called